# How to add computed field to LEI Replication Activity?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'm trying to build LEI Replication Activity to pull new/updates from DB2 to Notes (one way only).
Everything seems clear when I create connection and activity documents and map fields. But I want to compute all other hidden fields on Notes document when it's created. E.g. Readers field. How can I make sure it's added to new created Notes document when replicated from DB2? Or it's automatically computed?
Where do I define this field in LEI then?

Comment: Try to create an agent that runs on new documents and use `ComputeWithForm` method.

Comment: That was my assumption. But I thought there is LEI standard way to do it...

Comment: It's been quite a while (5+ years) since I've done this, but IIRC there is a way to define to at least define constants for importing.  I don't know that you can use a formula, but I think you can at least have a constant like a group name for your readers field.  I seem to recall the biggest issue was trying to figure out the syntax it was looking for.